# How to make player restrict of boundries in phaser js game?

Tags: phaser-framework

[image]

my code is here ( https://www.codepile.net/pile/7mPpA9m0 ) the player is go out of box of canvans how to make it restrict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the method `setCollideWorldBounds` on the players physics object, than the player should not be able to leave, teh Zone.

In the `create` function just add this line of code: `this.player.body.setCollideWorldBounds(true);`